# Filling a line chart with generated data in TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, jvm, linechart, variadic, tornadofx

I'm trying to turn a table of data into a series of line charts with TornadoFX. Each line in the table should correspond to a named line in the chart. As a start, I've followed the [TornadoFX guide](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/8.%20Charts.md), but this only covers the use case with hard coded values.

This is the TornadoFX guide example:

```
linechart("Unit Sales Q2 2016", CategoryAxis(), NumberAxis()) {

    multiseries("Product X", "Product Y") {
        data("MAR", 10245, 28443)
        data("APR", 23963, 22845)
        data("MAY", 15038, 19045)
    }
}
```

I was successful in creating the labels for the series, but that was about it:

```
val multiSeriesHeader = table.columHeaders.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()

linechart("Unit Sales Q2 2016", CategoryAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
    multiseries(*multiSeriesHeader) {
        // Here I want something like:
        // multidata( array of lines in the matrix, in the "data" format )
    }
}
```

My end goal is a way to "automatically generate" new lines of `data("Month", values...)` so I can create more lines to the chart by appending more values to a list of "line-data". However, I feel utterly lost with the way the `linechart` method creates the line chart and how the subsequent calls to `multiseries` and `data` translate into arguments (via these blocks).

I am new to TornadoFX and somewhat new with Kotlin. So, I don't know if there is a trick in the language or the library that would solve my problem. Help is be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would the chart values be bound to the list of objects (meaning the chart would change immediately be seen in the chart) or would it be more like a button generating the chart from the list (no live change, just when button clicked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list `myList` with respective properties `a b c` in each element then `data()` can be called for each item using looping in `myList` i.e.

```
myList.forEach { item ->
    data( item.a, item.b, item.c)
}
```

instead of manually calling `data()` for each data point